# Can the server respond with content-length less than requested range if proper headers are used

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, html5-video

I am developing a Node-JS server with some custom behavior for video streaming.

Server is exposing a file as stream on the root path `localhost:3000/` and listens for range requests. On the frontend there is a html5 video player which I have noticed by logging, request from in range values `current-byte to total-bytes` when you scrub on the timeline.

For now I am just piping the file-stream into the response.

My scenario requires me to query another process about the file in question and only pipe down the part of file that it allows me to. Now my question is if the player requests for example from byte 0 to 1000 and I respond with 0 to 100 and I set the headers like below, would the player understand that it didnt get the full data it wanted and make any subsequent requests.

```
 const range = fromOtherProcess(); // the other process told me this range is allowed
 response.statusCode = 206; // parital content
 response.setHeader('Content-Length', range.end - range.start + 1);
 response.setHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes ' + range.start + '-' + range.end + '/' + size);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't satisfy the requested range, you want to respond with 416, and include a Content-Range header telling the client what the satisfiable range actually is. See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/416

If you're really going to handle range requests yourself, you probably want to read the RFC. You need to gracefully handle badly formatted requests, unknown units, multiple ranges, etc. The page I linked above has a link to the current RFC.

Comment: OK that sounds good. Anything about the second part of question. How does HTML5 video tag behaves in this case. Would it take the response and play as normal and when it reaches the end of that partial response. Would it automatically make a new request of from: new_starting_byte to:end_byte

Comment: Do you mean how will the browser respond if you send back the response you described, instead of a 416?

Comment: I mean if I did send out 416 and the partial content, would the browser (video player) stop asking for more once it has consumed it, or will it make a subsequent request.

Comment: Don't send anything back but the Content-Range header, and then the browser (or any well behaved client) should send a new request for the available bytes.